# Where to publish a short (mathematical) neuroscience article?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, mathematical-psychology

I am writing an article about a computational method, which is relatively widely used in a small subfield of neuroscience (it is easy to identify ~20 recent articles that used it in 2013-2015).

The results I have are a set of small improvements but interesting anyway (at least in my opinion), so the paper will be a short one, perhaps around 2000 words (+ 1 or 2 figures and about 30 references). The results are purely mathematical; no data was collected.

Where could I publish my findings? I feel the upper-tier journals (with impact factors > 5 or so) might not be interested since the paper is so short (their typical paper lengths are 10+ pages). The top journals (e.g Nat Neurosci) of course publish brief reports but my findings are probably not that important.

Any suggestions where to submit?

Comment: If you have money for the publication and depending on the actual content, `PLOS One`, `PLOS Computational Biology`, or `Frontiers in Neuroscience` (note that frontiers is currently somewhat loosing reputation) could work. Alternatively, `Behavior Research Methods` might be an outlet, but I am not sure how open they are to Neuroscience (as I am not a neurscience person I post this as a comment instead a response).